# A new and random initialization vector always results in the same ciphertext during encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I have read a few threads on here about the proper use of Initialization Vectors and am in the process of re factoring some existing code to use random IVs per item.

I have a method which takes a blob of data and a key, and should encrypt the blob using the provided key and a random IV.

```
public static byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] output = new byte[0];

    Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(key));

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        acp.GenerateIV();
        byte[] vector = acp.IV;
        using (ICryptoTransform trans = acp.CreateEncryptor(key, vector))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Vector: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(vector));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, trans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                {
                    bw.Write(vector);
                    bw.Write(data);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    output = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(output));
    return output;
}
```

The intention is to prevent generation of the same cryptogram for the same data input and key. Unfortunately, although the console output shows a different IV being generated each time, multiple calls to the method using the same data and key result in the same cryptogram.

```
Data: 4761739001010010
Key: 7C-26-D9-6B-A1-FC-9E-67-9A-A2-7D-5F-52-5C-09-54-FE-DD-A5-C6-90-DD-0F-B3-CC-E2-7E-0E-4F-2D-2E-97
Vector: ED-02-6E-C6-B3-7A-74-66-4B-E5-47-23-16-D6-87-3B
Output: CB-F7-93-16-64-24-E2-F0-81-00-99-DA-97-F1-46-43-7D-F7-C4-AC-2E-C8-D4-D9-F1-7C-67-6E-F3-14-F0-4F-C7-1B-02-AE-41-4C-6B-B9-80-3A-64-4B-14-10-60-1B

Data: 4761739001010010
Key: 7C-26-D9-6B-A1-FC-9E-67-9A-A2-7D-5F-52-5C-09-54-FE-DD-A5-C6-90-DD-0F-B3-CC-E2-7E-0E-4F-2D-2E-97
Vector: 3E-3B-32-FB-82-03-03-9F-54-96-67-AA-29-5E-09-C4
Output: CB-F7-93-16-64-24-E2-F0-81-00-99-DA-97-F1-46-43-7D-F7-C4-AC-2E-C8-D4-D9-F1-7C-67-6E-F3-14-F0-4F-C7-1B-02-AE-41-4C-6B-B9-80-3A-64-4B-14-10-60-1B
```

Any idea where this is going wrong?

Comment: I bielieve you need to specify the Mode for your Cyrpto Provider

Comment: @XtremeBytes The default mode seems to be `CBC`, so there should be different encryption results if the vector changes..... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44442/using-aescryptoserviceprovider-in-c-should-using-an-incorrect-iv-mangle-just-t

Answer (score 1):

I have not used a Binary writer for encryption. This is the code I tired and it seems to work fine

```
public static byte[] AesEncrypt(string toEncrypt, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] output = new byte[0];

    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);

    Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(key));

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        acp.GenerateIV();
        byte[] vector = acp.IV;
        using (ICryptoTransform trans = acp.CreateEncryptor(key, vector))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Vector: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(vector));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, trans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                //using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    //bw.Write(vector);
                    //bw.Write(data);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    output = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", BitConverter.ToString(output));
    return output;
}
```

However have not tested the Decrypt part. If you are using a random IV as in this example, not sure how you are planning to decrypt it later.

Comment: The `BinaryWriter` has nothing to do with it, since you'll get the same behavior if you comment the line where you write the vector first (what you did in your answer)

Comment: You don't output the IV at all, so it won't be possible to decrypt the first block of the message.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is actually the correct behavior......

The problem is that the first thing you write to your encryption stream is the vector.

If you take a look at this link: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44442/using-aescryptoserviceprovider-in-c-should-using-an-incorrect-iv-mangle-just-t

it explains that the first operation in CBC mode is to XOR the data you provide (the vector in your case), with the vector provided.
So basically, whatever vector you provide, the first data to be encrypted (after the XOR operation) will be composed of `0`
see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

The next vector used will be the first encrypted block of data, so the `0` encrypted with your key, that's why you won't see any difference whatever vector you provide.

If you just comment this line:

```
bw.Write(vector);
```

You'll see the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to encrypt the IV, but rather write that out as plaintext, then encrypt everything else.

So instead of:

```
bw.Write(vector);
```

You would do:

```
ms.Write(vector, 0, vector.Length);
```

That way, the first 16 bytes of your output will be the IV, which will be needed when it comes time to decrypt the message.

Comment: Thanx Joe that was the last piece of the puzzle